# How I can achieve this kind of table in css with the align on the body content

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've been making a table for a week similar to the program below. The program is created from scratch and I done it through CSS I just want to ask some help on how I can align the header with the body content. I'm using div tag as a table to achieve it. And also if ever is it possible on the default html table tag?

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border: none;
}

.table .tbody .tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}

.table .tbody .tr .td {
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 18px 10px;
}

.table .thead .tr {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.table .thead .tr .th {
  display: table-column;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class=" table">
    <div class="thead">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="th" style="width: 20%;">Name</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 35%;">Description</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 25%;">Email</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 20%;">Location</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Action</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- table body -->
    <div class="tbody">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">John</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 35%;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">john@example.com</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Delete</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Mary</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 35%;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">john@example.com</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Delete</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">July</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 35%;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">july@example.com</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Delete</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the misalignment was caused by the border on your table-td rows. I added a transparent border-left to the table head, which fixed the issue. please note that the last column text isn't CSS left align which is causing it appears to be misaligned

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border: none;
}

.table .tbody .tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}

.table .tbody .tr .td {
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 18px 10px;
}

.table .thead .tr {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.table .thead .tr .th {
  display: table-column;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class=" table">
    <div class="thead">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="th" style="width: 20%;">Name</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 35%;">Description</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 25%;">Email</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 20%;">Location</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Action</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- table body -->
    <div class="tbody">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">John</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 35%;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 25%;">john@example.com</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Delete</div>
      </div>

 <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">John</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 35%;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 25%;">john@example.com</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Delete</div>
      </div>

 <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">John</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 35%;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 25%;">john@example.com</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Delete</div>
      </div>

 <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">John</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 35%;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 25%;">john@example.com</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%;">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">Delete</div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width percentage in your header do not match the ones in the table. Also, I think the sum of them should be 100%.

Comment: thank you can you give some sort of example?